# How to make use of 'Date of birth' column to send birthday greetings

Tags: php, sql

I am writing a script to select all people from a database whose month and day of birth fall on the current month and day and send them birthday greetings by e-mail. What I need is just the SQL code, I would then pick up from there and then tie it to my cron job.

I have used a number of codes which could not run. The code I used last is:

```
select name_of_staff, 
  email, 
  date_of_birth  
from staff_dossier 
WHERE month(date_of_birth) = month(now()) 
  AND dayofmonth(date_of_birth) = dayofmonth(now());
```

//send mail code follows...

My problem is to extract only the month and day parts in the `date_of_birth` column where necessary and use it to determine to whom the birthday greetings go.

May someone please help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the list of employees with a birth month and date that matches current date/month, you should be able to use the functions [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [`DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day):

```
select name_of_staff, email, date_of_birth  
from staff_dossier 
WHERE month(date_of_birth) = month(now()) 
  AND day(date_of_birth) = day(now());
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f0c/2)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was solved.

Answer (score 1):

use date_format()

```
select name_of_staff, 
email, 
date_of_birth  
from staff_dossier
Where
date_format(date_of_birth,'%d %m') = date_format(curdate(),'%d %m');
```

Comment: Thanks a hip!. solved.

Comment: accept the answer so others wont have to look again